# Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers includes

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, toolchain, gnu-toolchain

I am struggling including a file in one project. I don't know why eclipse is not able to find the header file. The file is named boards.h, inside a folder named bsp, and everything seems fine

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set project specific paths under C/C++ Build > Settings > C Compiler > Includes Solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your include path starts with a / which is the root of your filesystem and I'm pretty sure your ipv6_coap__client folder isn't in the root of your filesystem. I think simply specifying only the subfolder `bsp` should do as the compiler tends to work relative to your projects location. If that fails try `${workspace_loc}/ipv6_coap_client/bsp`

Comment: no, but the check "Is a workspace path" is ON

Comment: anyway, I've tried now with the full path with the same result

Comment: If you scroll to the right in your build output can you verify the correct path is passed to the compiler on the commandline? (should start with -I)

Comment: true it's not getting the path propery ( -I/ipv6_coap_client/bsp -) but i cleaned and set it 100 times :-(

Comment: I think you are settings it in the wrong place. Your language selection there is on assembly. Should be on GNU C. Also these are the general settings it would be better to set project specific paths under C/C++ Build >  Settings > C Compiler > Includes

Comment: true, It was this, thanks @Eelke